# looping over regression, treating a constant as a variable. ERROR: variable lengths differ

Tags: r, regression, lm

I want to loop over the inclusion / exclusion of certain variable but I ran into an error. Here's the problem with some sample data.

```
mtcars = data('mtcars')
for(i in 0:1) {
  fitlm = lm(mpg ~ cyl + i *  drat, data = mtcars)
}
Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg ~ cyl + i * drat, data = mtcars,  : variable lengths differ (found for 'i')
```

But then this will run without a problem:

```
fitlm = lm(mpg ~ cyl + 0 *  drat, data = mtcars)
fitlm = lm(mpg ~ cyl + 1 *  drat, data = mtcars)
```

Why do the regressions work if there's a number multiplier of the variable, but fail if it's `i`?

Comment: I'm testing different lags (ex: `lag(cyl, i)`, and the presences / absence of certain variables. So in the above example when `i` is `0`, drat will be dropped from the regression.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `as.formula` as follows:

```
# create an empty list to store the results 
fitlm <- list()

# loop, fit the model and assign the result to a new list in fitlm
for(i in 0:1) {
      fitlm[[i+1]] <- lm(as.formula(paste("mpg ~ cyl +", i, "*  drat")), data = mtcars) 
    }
```

You can also use `purrr::map` instead of loops as follows:

```
fitlm <- purrr::map(c(0,1), ~lm(as.formula(paste("mpg ~ cyl +", .x, "*  drat")), data = mtcars))
```

And the result will be:

```
> fitlm
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~ cyl +", i, "*  drat")), 
    data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
 cyl  
2.79  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = as.formula(paste("mpg ~ cyl +", i, "*  drat")), 
    data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl  
     37.885       -2.876
```

Comment: Does `map` iterate over all possible combinations if I had more than one `.x` in the regression? Or would I need a `map` for every different I'd want to alternate?

Comment: .x here corresponds to c(0,1). What do you mean by more than .x? more than one variable to exclude/include?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could try something of the form

```
fitlm = list()
for(i in 0:1) {
  idrat = i*mtcars$drat
  fitlm[[i+1]] = lm(mpg ~ cyl + idrat, data = mtcars)
}
```

which gives the result

```
fitlm
## [[1]]
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + idrat, data = mtcars)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          cyl        idrat  
##      37.885       -2.876           NA  
## 
## 
## [[2]]
## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + idrat, data = mtcars)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          cyl        idrat  
##      28.725       -2.484        1.872
```

This gets around the `lm()` function looking for interactions when it sees the `*` character, as you found when using a number.